# What is the best way to access an integer value from multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, volatile, interlocked

I'm confused about how to choose the most effective way to synchronize multi threads.
Supposed we have an integer value **i** to synchronize.

1. 1-Write/1-Read : just simply ignore it or add **volatile** before i?
2. 1-Write/N-Read : just simply ignore it or add **volatile** before i?
3. N-Write/1-Read : Interlocked is the best way.
4. N-Write/1-Read : Interlocked is the best way.

Should i use **volatile**, **Interlocked** or **lock**?

Comment: "volatile" is sort of an advanced topic. With that carries an expectation of base level knowledge. It would be a lot easier to understand your problem if you can show us an example use case, and your understanding of what's going on.

Comment: I will say try ```static```..

Comment: Forget Volatile it doesn't do what you think it does. If you use lock, you have to remember to lock it everywhere. If you use interlock, is safer because it's locked everywehere, you won't need to lock it anywhere else, it's safe even on different cpus and cors.

Comment: Integers are a bit of a special case. Reads and writes to a 4 byte integer are guaranteed to be atomic on all .NET platforms: you can be a little less careful when you are working with ints. I tend to use Interlocked though; I believe it creates the appropriate memory barriers in place

Comment: I am surprised that you are searching for the most effective way, and not for the correct way. Will you be satisfied with an answer that proclaims to be very effective (by some arbitrary definition of "effective"), that causes your program to produce incorrect results?

Comment: @Train - Please explain what you mean by "If you use interlock, is safer because it's locked everywehere"?